# CSS3 Transformation while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, transformation

Does anyone know of a good tutorial to achieve this? (as seen here: http://www.contrastrebellion.com/)
I've looked at the code used on that site and finding it awkward to pull out what I need.

Much appreciated,
Thanks

Edit: Also seen here: http://playgroundinc.com/

What I want to achieve:

To rotate a png as I scroll down and the speed of rotation to match the speed of scrolling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction : http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/code-tutorials/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/ .

Here you go :

For animating the rotation on scroll .

http://jsfiddle.net/EnSkJ/2/

Code :

```
var sdegree = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    sdegree ++ ;
    sdegree = sdegree + 3 ;
    var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
    $("img").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll look through that. I'm not sure if will directly achieve what I want however as I want to just rotate a png as I scroll down and the speed to match the speed of scrolling, rather than move layers of images to get a parallax effect.

Comment: Updated the answer with a fiddle , it's not perfect but gives you the basics.

Comment: Would it be possible to make it always be the correct way round when you scroll back to the top?

Comment: yep , I had to ask a question to work it out though :) http://jsfiddle.net/EnSkJ/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use a simple way like [Infra Stank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113535/1250044). However if you need a more complex thing to *"animate"* try [jQuery Transe](https://github.com/yckart/jquery.transe.js). It is a *thorough* solution for exactly this problem. You can change almost anything based on the current scroll offset (even CSS3-Transforms and suchlike).

In your case, try something like this:

```
$('img').transe({
    start: 0,
    end: 1600,
    css: 'transform',
    from: 'rotate(0deg)',
    to: 'rotate(360deg)'
});
```

**[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vTk5x/)**

BTW: If you like smooth things, you can include [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) with its CSS-Plugin.