# Make div appear when almost visible

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-waypoints

I found this website: http://dem2.olevmedia.net/beep/

If you scroll down the divs are loaded with animation. If I look in the source I can't find any scripts that could be relevant, only css classes and data functions.

How is this effect called? and where can I find this? 
I think this is a combination with jquery waypoints. But I don't know how it's done.

Comment: This is not loading just applying css effects..

Comment: But when are the animations applied? Is that done using waypoints?

Comment: That is using jquery addClass and removeClass functions

Comment: Could you provide a link to a tutorial for a similar thing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EnSkJ/2/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113292/css3-transformation-while-scrolling

Comment: That kind of an awesome example you're using there! Will look at it and try something myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: [jQuery Appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear).

This is the [Demo Page](http://morr.github.io/appear.html).